# How to convert the given string to desired string as shown below in Python

Tags: python, string

Given string:

`p\u00e5 \u00e5rsbasis i marts.<br><br>P\u00e5 \u00e5rsbasis faldt industriproduktionen 0,6 procent (-0,3) mod analytikerkonsensus, der afventede et fald p\u00e5 0,8 procent.<br><br><table><tbody><tr><td>Eurozonen, %<\/td><td>marts, 2019<\/td><td>Konsensus<\/td><td>februar, 2019<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>Industriproduktion, YY<\/td><td>-0,6<\/td><td>-0,8<\/td><td>-0,3<\/td><\/tr><\/tbody><\/table>Konsensusdata`

Desired string:

`på årsbasis i marts.<br><br>På årsbasis faldt industriproduktionen 0,6 procent (-0,3) mod analytikerkonsensus, der afventede et fald på 0,8 procent.<br><br><table><tbody><tr><td>Eurozonen, %</td><td>marts, 2019</td><td>Konsensus</td><td>februar, 2019</td></tr><tr><td>Industriproduktion, YY</td><td>-0,6</td><td>-0,8</td><td>-0,3</td></tr></tbody></table>Konsensusdata`

Comment: From your question, we can not even guess it the first string is a unicode (normal Python 3) string or a byte (Python 2) string. And it matters. It means that the question is *unclear*. I really think that you should read (again?) [ask] :-).

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
string = b"p\u00e5 \u00e5rsbasis i marts.<br><br>P\u00e5 \u00e5rsbasis faldt industriproduktionen 0,6 procent (-0,3) mod analytikerkonsensus, der afventede et fald p\u00e5 0,8 procent.<br><br><table><tbody><tr><td>Eurozonen, %<\/td><td>marts, 2019<\/td><td>Konsensus<\/td><td>februar, 2019<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>Industriproduktion, YY<\/td><td>-0,6<\/td><td>-0,8<\/td><td>-0,3<\/td><\/tr><\/tbody><\/table>Konsensusdata"
print(string.decode('unicode_escape'))
```

Output:

> 'på årsbasis i marts.
> På årsbasis faldt industriproduktionen 0,6 procent (-0,3) mod analytikerkonsensus, der afventede et fald på 0,8 procent.
> Eurozonen, %<\/td>marts, 2019<\/td>Konsensus<\/td>februar, 2019<\/td><\/tr>Industriproduktion, YY<\/td>-0,6<\/td>-0,8<\/td>-0,3<\/td><\/tr><\/tbody><\/table>Konsensusdata'